# SQL INSERT INTO Syntax error. Basic Database

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm attempting to insert a new row into a table and I am getting a syntax error. I successfully inserted rows into different tables in the same database withe the same format with no issues. The scrip is as follows

```
INSERT INTO Ordertbl(OrdNo, OrdDate, CustNo, EmpNo, OrdName, OrdStreet, OrdCity, OrdState, OrdZip)
VALUES ('O1234567', '2030-1-25', '49908905', '55138445', 'John Smith', 'Milwaukee', 'WI', '53122-4523')
```

Comment: You list nine columns but are only giving eight values. It looks like you forgot to supply an `OrdStreet`. Also, MKE props.

Comment: "A syntax error" is not very descriptive. When asking for help try and to supply that as well. I've found MySQL to be very, very specific when it points out mistakes. Read carefully what it says. Check the reference material whenever you have problems.

Comment: What's the point in coming along two hours after the question was answered and complaining that it wasn't specific enough?

Answer (score 5):

You specified nine columns but only eight values. You're missing the street.

Comment: Ahh classic. It works now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries, happens to all of us.